# Programatically download a report generated in Salesforce

Tags: reporting, data-export, reports-api

I would like to download a report generated in Salesforce every month as a csv file and process it on our side. I explored the analytic api which has a limit of 2000 rows per call, writing a soql query is a option but its cumbersome. Can I ftp the report to a location on our server once its generated in Salesforce? What would be the ideal way to download a report with 100k records?

Comment: If you could limit yourself to 25K rows, you could use Conga Composer/Conductor

Comment: NO I need to download entire report.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the apex Data Loader, there's a way to set it up using a batch file and Windows Task Scheduler. I set it up for a client, it's not actually too difficult to use :)

Check out these:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=command_line_intro.htm&language=en_US
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=using_the_command_line_interface.htm

Comment: The Data loader only allows data export of Salesforce objects but not Reports generated.

Comment: Correct, but a report is just data from Salesforce objects... you could run a query to export the exact data that you would export from the report...

Comment: Other than the other way is just scheduling the report or creating some custom APEX to actually get the content of a report that has been loaded then making the APEX generate the file.

Comment: You mean to write a SOQL query to get data and export using data loader?

Comment: I dont know APEX so I will have to learn it. After scheduling the report with Apex can apex push the report to my server?  Is there any way to change the default limit exposed on rest api call?

Comment: If you have a look at the Data Loader documentation they have basically done it all for you :) You just need to write the SOQL query and put it in place then run and you are good to go! As for APEX I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Thank you Timothy, I was successfully able to get report and insert the rows into our db2 database using Salesforce Dataloader on unix.